# Thread safe enumeration, add or removal of a collection in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, ienumerable, ienumerator, icollection

I have faced a question in interview I am not sure I understood it correctly . Would it really be real time scenario??
But I am trying my best to explain the problem

> Create a class that is to be collection(implement IEnumerable) and it will have a data structure(a dictionary) which will have very large chunk of data. User can iterate this data. But this class should also provide an option of adding and removing item to data structure. It is accessible to so many threads.
>   So while a thread is iterating over the collection other thread might be adding an item this collection. So, thread which is iterating should also retrieve the latest added item.

So how the class would look like

Answer (score 0):

Starting by version 4.0 .net already provides such kind of collections.

Take a look at the [System.Collections.Concurrent-Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).
And a deeper look into the `ConcurrentBag` and the `ConcurrentDictionary` classes.